# Postgresql query doesn't show all rows

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables `Invoice` belongs to `User` and user belongs to `Subsidiary`.

I want to know by month of the year how many invoices are by subsidiaris.

I have only 3 subsidiaries, `sub_a`, `sub_b` and `sub_c`

This is my query:

```sql
select
    s.id,
    s.name,
    COALESCE(COUNT(i.id), 0) AS sep_22
from subsidiaries s
left join users u on s.id = u.subsidiary_id
left join invoices i on u.id = i.user_id
WHERE i.created_at >= '2022-09-01'
      AND i.created_at <= '2022-09-30'
    group by (s.id, s.name);
```

Now in september of 2022 we don't have invoices for `sub_c` and it shows only 2 rows and I want to show the 3 rows with `0` if some subsidiary doesn't have invoice that month.

Current result:

| id | name | sep_22 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sub_a | 25 |
| 2 | sub_b | 12 |

But I want this:

| id | name | sep_22 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sub_a | 25 |
| 2 | sub_b | 12 |
| 3 | sub_c | 0 |

What can I do to achieve that?

I tried using `right join`, `join`, `left outer join`. Even changing the order of the query, but still got the same result.

```sql
select
        s.id,
        s.name,
        COALESCE(COUNT(i.id), 0) AS aug_22
    FROM invoices i
             LEFT JOIN .users u ON i.user_id = u.id
             LEFT JOIN subsidiaries s on u.subsidiary_id = s.id
    WHERE i.created_at >= '2022-08-01'
      AND i.created_at <= '2022-08-31'
    group by (s.id, s.name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current `WHERE` restriction on the created date is filtering off certain names which do not fall within that range.  Move this criterion to the `ON` clause of the join to avoid this.

```sql
SELECT
    s.id,
    s.name,
    COUNT(i.id) AS sep_22
FROM subsidiaries s
LEFT JOIN users u 
    s.id = u.subsidiary_id
LEFT JOIN invoices i
    ON u.id = i.user_id AND
       i.created_at BETWEEN '2022-09-01' AND '2022-09-30'
GROUP BY
    s.id,
    s.name;
```